# Beta Software (eg Windows 8 at this time) Too Localized?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, too-localized

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should we have a sub-tag for beta/RC?](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/3447/should-we-have-a-sub-tag-for-beta-rc)

Would not any beta software (such as Windows 8 at this time) be considered too localized since it is subject to change and thus should be closed?

Comment: Hmm, I did a search before posting and did not find the other question. This just shows that the search function is not very good. `:-(` Thanks for the link.

Comment: try `site:meta.superuser.com beta software` in Google next time... :)

Comment: I tried searching for *beta too localized* in the search box at the top and in the title of the *post-new-question* form. I tried your suggestion and it did not work, however using Google with my terms *did* work (first result). I guess I’ll be using Google to check for existing questions from now instead of the built-in one. `:-D`

Comment: how did I get notified of this comment? anyways, yeah, Google's always gonna be better unfortunately :(

Comment: *> how did I get notified of this comment?*, beats me; I’ve wondered that numerous times. I suspect it has the ability to detect a “conversation” between two people and/or it has something to do with the comment you see when trying to add two @ tags to a comment.

Comment: @studiohack You're notified if the post's author writes a comment and there is nobody but you and the post's author in the comment thread. Now that I posted, you'll not get notified without @-mention about the next comment of Synetech.

Comment: @Daniel, so I was right about conversation-detection. Nice. `:-)`

Comment: @DanielBeck that's what I suspected. :) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would say that it depends. If the person is talking about a bu in the OS, then maybe, but if they are just asking for how to do something if the OS is working properly, then it is probably OK.

Comment: "asking for how to do something if the OS is working properly" I don't understand this at all..

Comment: Printing, networking, etc in windows 8, how to use the metro UI, things like that.