# Retag windows-8 as windows-8-preview

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request

As of now, Windows 8 is not out, and as such, all questions with tag [windows-8](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/windows-8) really relate to the preview, and should be retagged as such to [windows-8-preview](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/windows-8-preview)

This is in line with implementing the answer to [Should we have a sub-tag for beta/RC?](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/3447/should-we-have-a-sub-tag-for-beta-rc).

Comment: Kind of confused. My post is in line with the accepted answer of that post...

Comment: just because it's accepted doesn't mean it's right

Comment: My question was about implementing the accepted answer of a different question. I don't think that really classifies it as a dupe

Comment: You did not indicate that in any way here

Comment: It is asking to retag all the questions that have windows-8 to windows-8-preview... How is that not about implementation?

Comment: You said "implement the accepted answer", well, maybe if you had indicated something to do with that, it might not have looked as such. In its current state, this question is a duplicate

Comment: Edited. That what you meant?

Comment: Yes. Voted to reopen

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
updating post history, 51 rows affected
updating posts, 35 rows affected
updating PostTags associations, 10 rows affected
removing/renaming old tag, 1 rows affected
updating count for master tag, 1 rows affected
tag remapping of [windows-8-preview] and [windows-8] complete!
remapping 0 synonyms
34 favorite and ignored tags remapped!
Tag Synonym windows-8 -> windows-8-preview was approved!
```

---

Done. The synonym will be dropped later once Windows 8 is released.

Comment: Will we use a separate beta tag once that is released? We should remap the synonym then probably.

Comment: @DanielBeck No, I'd already mapped windows-8-beta to windows-8-preview while doing this

Answer (score 1):

Well, the consensus was edit them as we see them, and thats pretty much what ought to be done.