# When would editing or adding the 'regular' windows 8 tag be appropriate?

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What will happen to the Windows-8-Preview tag once Windows 8 goes live?](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/5167/what-will-happen-to-the-windows-8-preview-tag-once-windows-8-goes-live)

Now that windows 8 is out (and soon to be released), we've come to the point where we almost need to retire the windows-8-preview tag.

For reference, these questions cover the creation and reasoning behind the preview tags

[Retag windows-8 as windows-8-preview](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/4377/retag-windows-8-as-windows-8-preview) 
[Should we have a sub-tag for beta/RC?](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/3447/should-we-have-a-sub-tag-for-beta-rc)

I personally think unless the OP is running a RTM/Release version the preview tag is appropriate. There isn't really consensus on this - https://superuser.com/review/suggested-edits/43546 As I see it, the question is *clearly* about windows 8 cp, and such should have the preview flag. On the other hand, at least 3 people disagree.

So, what should the status of the preview tag be? How do we handle these? When is, and when isn't a retag appropriate?

Answer (score 1):

[windows-8](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/windows-8) shouldn't have been added to that question, it's inherently specific only to the preview as I've mentioned. I've rolled back the edit.

That said, the preview tag is applicable when the user's mentioned he's on Windows 8 preview. As mentioned in the linked questions, soon we'll start taking a look at [windows-8-preview](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/windows-8-preview) questions and transition them to closed questions.