# Could we have a Windows 10 tag?

Tags: support, tags

I just asked a question about Windows 10, and I noticed there isn't a tag yet. Could it be worth setting one up now, so it's in the correct format etc?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd say it's time for the tag when there is an actual Windows 10 version available that people can get their hands on.

Similar to [our process for the Windows 8 Preview](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/4377/retag-windows-8-as-windows-8-preview), we'd first start with a dedicated tag for this early version, and only once the *real* one is out in the wild, use an official tag. We'd then [check whether questions that were posted with the preview tag are also applicable to the final version](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/5167/what-will-happen-to-the-windows-8-preview-tag-once-windows-8-goes-live), and retag if necessary.

At this point in time, I don't see any on-topic question carrying an "official" Windows 10 tag, sorry.

Comment: Ahh, okay. That makes sense :).

Comment: Side note: I've just seen the comments on my original question, and I removed it seeing as it was down as off topic, and I couldn't see anyway to turn it into a better question.

Comment: @TomHart I don't know what your question was, but if it becomes useful once the OS is released, consider un-deleting it.

Comment: It wouldn't be, it was asking if anyone know when the preview is available. The promo video said visit a link and sign up, but on the page there was no sign up, or date for when you could.

Comment: @TomHart - It has not been released.  It will be located [here](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/preview-coming-soon) `Windows Insider Preview Program` which opens today ( 10/1/2014 ).  If rumors are correct it will be an evolving technical preview, so the initial version release won't be the same as the last update to it.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like both the tags were created anyway and in the meantime people have gotten a hold of the preview.

I've gone ahead and synonymised [windows-10](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/windows-10) with [windows-10-preview](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/windows-10-preview).  As with Windows 7 and 8 features can and do change before official release so once it is officially RTM'ed then the synonym can be split.