# Fair application of non-existent rules

Tags: discussion, support

Previously we had a discussion about ReactOS. Essentially there isn't a rule against asking about "pre-release" software, but those questions were closed because ReactOS is declared perpetually "alpha" (despite having hundreds of developers and thousands of users and write ups in major non-tech publications).

Likewise, I suggested we look at other questions as examples of **why we should not target just one users submissions in just one tag**. Those questions did not make a convincing argument against the organized hordes of SuperUser.

I'd like to make a different suggestion then. Let's just delete all the questions,

- Debian Testing (610 questions): https://superuser.com/search?q=Debian+Testing+is%3Aquestion
- Ubuntu Testing (18.10 is released in Oct 2018) https://superuser.com/search?q=Ubuntu+18.10
- Chrome Beta https://superuser.com/search?q=%22Chrome+Beta%22+is%3Aquestion
- Windows 8 Preview (392 Questions) https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/windows-8-preview
- Windows 10 Preview (332 Questions) https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/windows-10-preview

At least that would start us down principled path of creating and enforcing rules rather than just making them up to target a specific user.

And, following the logic from others I don't use any of that software above, so I should be partial and passionate about closing those questions?

Answer (score 6):

#### "Essentially there isn't a rule against asking about "pre-release" software"

Well meta did have a [discussion about this](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/6926/should-questions-related-to-problems-with-beta-software-prototype-hardware-be-cl).

The community consensus was that questions about software that was "perpetually in alpha" are off-topic.

All the examples you quote in your question relate to software that is **not** perpetually in alpha.

However, as Jeff said:

> once the OS is released, I support deleting all the beta and rc questions, or at least most of them AFTER THE OPERATING SYSTEM IS FULLY RELEASED.

So please feel free to cast your close votes on the examples in your question ...

Source [Should we have a sub-tag for beta/RC?](https://meta.superuser.com/a/3449/337631)