# Beating the beta tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-cleanup-request

Considering [we already recommend having a sub-tag for betas and RCs](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/3447/should-we-have-a-sub-tag-for-beta-rc), [beta](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/beta) is redundant. Can we get rid of it?

Comment: delta gamma omega

Comment: why have a tag saying **'DO NOT USE THIS TAG - Use tags specific to the software as appropriate'** - that's like saying **DO NOT PRESS THIS BUTTON. PRESS THE OTHER BUTTON INSTEAD.** I know the first thing people will do... :(

Comment: Does it cause a light to come on saying "Please do not press that button again", @jbutler483?

Comment: Alas, we are told we are not allowed to give painful jolts to people who do this. Also, it sort of *hopefully* discourages people from using the tag while we clean it up

Answer (score 1):

The tag [beta](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/beta) has been removed in its entirety.